# Hola, estoy intentando mostrar una tabla ordenada y quiero ir enumerando en filas pero me los agrega en columnas

Tags: php, html, foreach, table

aqui les indico el codigo si me funciona la operacion irme contando hasta un limite dado por $resulcant pero al momento de mostrarlo en la tabla me muestra de manera horizontal pero debe ser vertical tiene que ir enumerando cada fila

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>$resulcant2 = 5 //valor ejemplo, este valor me lo da una consulta de count(*) a la base</p>
<?php
     echo "<table class='table table-hover' border='1'>";
     echo " <thead>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<th>#</th>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</thead>";
     
     echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr >";
     
     $Count = 0;
     while($Count < 5){
     ++$Count;
     $total[$Count] = $Count; 
     }
     foreach ($total as $value) {
     echo "<td>$value </td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "<tbody>";
  
     echo "</table>";
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: estas añadiendo los valores dentro de <td>, que es el indicador de columna. quita el primer <tr>, y en el echo del valor pones <tr><td>, para iniciar una fila y poner la primera columna con el valor

Comment: Hola @Jakala, el codigo si funciono pero solo si tengo una columna le añadi las demas columnas y no reacciona bien ya que empiezan a mostrar las desmas consultas luego de finalizar el contador y se muestra junto a la ultima fila del contador

Comment: Para que te imprima una fila por cada iteracción del bucle **tendrías que poner el `<tr>` dentro del bucle, no fuera de él**. Por ejemplo: `foreach ($total as $value) {
     echo "<tr><td>$value </td></tr>";
     }` Por otra parte, me parece que el `while` es innecesario, desde el `for` puedes controlar la cantidad de filas y limitarla a cinco. Aunque me pregunto por qué no filtras ` $total` en el origen. Traer datos para luego desecharlos podría revelar un error de concepto en cualquier parte.

Comment: @A.Cedano te cuento que si luego lo tengo con un for sencillo 

for ($x = 1; $x <= $resulcant2; $x++) {echo "<tr><td>$x </td></tr>";}

pero me aparece un problema que dos veces me repite el proceso del for es decir ya me hace el proceso for una vez y vuelve nuevamente hacerlo  porque??

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta lo que imprime esto: `var_dump($total);`  (ponlo fuera de los bucles). Sin conocer la estructura de los datos con los que estás trabajando es complicado ayudarte a optimizar el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano como estas voy a dejarte el achivo completo .php este NO es el que graba pero si el que muestra la tabla de consultas, hice las instrucciones que me dijo pero me refleja la consulta dos veces porfavor dejare el codigo abajo

Comment: Es complicado revisar un programa completo, recomendaría que te centres en el problema concreto que planteas en la pregunta, y si surgen nuevas dudas, puedes abrir una nueva pregunta. Dicho eso, el área de abajo es para respuestas, cualquier aclaración sobre la pregunta pulsa en [eidt] y la agregas a  la misma pregunta. En cuanto al código, aparte de varias malas prácticas que deberás corregir más adelante (si quieres luego te las enumero), lo que puede estar causando la repetición de resultados es que estás ejecutando a `$sql2` dentro de un bucle  `for`...

Comment: ... significa que los datos se mostrarán tantas veces como elementos haya dentro de ese bucle. Una de las malas prácticas que veo en tu código es que todo esto podría resolverse con una sola consulta, relacionando las tablas. Pero ese es otro asunto. Sugiero que intentes corregir el código actual, y cuando funcione entonces podrás pensar en optimizarlo / mejorarlo. Pues no es por desanimarte, pero tu código requiere varias mejoras. Y conviene que aprendas ciertas prácticas que te van a ahorrar muchas horas perdidas depurando y muchos dolores de cabeza (y de vista).

Answer (score 0):

el problema lo tienes en esta parte del codigo:

```
 echo "<tbody>";
 echo "<tr >";
 
 $Count = 0;
 while($Count < 5){
 ++$Count;
 $total[$Count] = $Count; 
 }
 foreach ($total as $value) {
 echo "<td>$value </td>";
 }
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "<tbody>";
```

inicializas un tr, (indicador de fila) y luego dentro haces varios  (indicador de columna). Para ponerlos en una fila cada uno, tienes que englobarlos dentro del foreach.

```
 echo "<tbody>";    //quito el tr de la siguiente linea   
 $Count = 0;
 while($Count < 5){
 ++$Count;
 $total[$Count] = $Count; 
 }
 foreach ($total as $value) {
 echo "<tr><td>$value </td></tr>"; // engloba en fila y columna tu valor
 }
 echo "<tbody>"; // quito el tr anterior
```

con esto lo tendras fila a fila.

por otra parte, el bucle while no tiene mucho sentido (supongo que sera una forma para ponerlo de ejemplo en stackoverflow). Pero si no lo es, puedes cambiar el bucle foreach por un bucle for normal:

```
 echo "<tbody>";    //quito el tr de la siguiente linea   
 for($Count=0; $count<5; $count++) { // te puedes ahorrar el bucle while
     echo "<tr><td>$value </td></tr>"; // engloba en fila y columna tu valor
     echo "<tbody>"; // quito el tr anterior
```

Comment: Hola @Jakala, el codigo si funciono pero solo si tengo una columna le añadi las demas columnas y no reacciona bien ya que empiezan a mostrar las desmas consultas luego de finalizar el contador y se muestra junto a la ultima fila del contador

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php include('sesion2.php');?>

<html>
<Head>
<?php include('head_meta.php');?>
<?php include('head_boostrap.php');?>
<?php include('head_favicon.php');?>
<?php include('combos_box.php');?>
<title>NOTAS</title>
</Head>

<body class="admin">
<section class="caja">
<?php include('menu.php');?>
<?php include('ayuda.php');?>
<h3>Lista de Notas</h3>
<?php include('filtro_notas.php');?>
<?php include('conexion.php');;?>

<form action="../php/notas_graba.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php

if ($_SESSION['rol']== 2 || $_SESSION['rol']== 1)
    {
    echo('
    <a class="btn nuevo" href="lista_notas_filtro.php">Crear Nota</a>
    ');

        $nivel=$_GET['nivel'];
        $especialidad=$_GET['especialidad'];
        $curso=$_GET['curso'];
        $paralelo=$_GET['paralelo'];
        $materia=$_GET['materia'];

        $inivel=$_GET['inivel'];
        $iespecialidad=$_GET['iespecialidad'];
        $icurso=$_GET['icurso'];
        $iparalelo=$_GET['iparalelo'];
        $id_materia=$_GET['id_materia'];
        
            if($_SESSION['rol']==1){
            $idocente=$_SESSION['id'];
            }
            else{
            $idocente=$_GET['idocente'];
            }
    }

//estudiante
elseif ($_SESSION['rol']== 0 )
{
        $nivel= $_SESSION['nivel'];
        $especialidad= $_SESSION['especiali'];
        $curso= $_SESSION['curso'];
        $paralelo= $_SESSION['paralelo'];
        $id= $_SESSION['id'];
}

?>

<br><br>

<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="">NIVEL :</span></div>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $nivel?>"  class="form-control" readonly>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>   

<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="">ESPECIALIDAD :</span></div>    
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $especialidad?>" class="form-control" readonly>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="">CURSO :</span></div>   
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $curso?>" class="form-control" readonly>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="">PARALELO :</span></div>    
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $paralelo?>" class="form-control" readonly>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 mb-3"></div>

<div class="col-md-4 mb-1 input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="">MATERIA :</span></div> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $materia?>" class="form-control" readonly>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>     

<div class="col-md-12 mb-3"></div>

<input name="nivel" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $inivel?>"  readonly>
<input name="especialidad" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $iespecialidad?>" readonly>
<input name="curso" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $icurso?>" readonly>
<input name="paralelo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $iparalelo?>" readonly>
<input name="materia" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $imateria?>" readonly>


<?php


//Aqui consultamos cuantos usuarios hay registrados en ese curso y los mostramos arriba de la tabla
$consulta41 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM  usuarios
WHERE 
ID_CURSO=$icurso AND
ID_NIVEL=$inivel AND
ID_PARALELO=$iparalelo AND
ID_ESPECIALI=$iespecialidad AND
ROL=0");
$row1001 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta41);  
$resulcant2 = $row1001[0];
echo 'Total de estudiantes en este curso= '.$resulcant2;


//consulta y muestra la lista de estudiantes que se encuentran registrados en ese curso al que fue creada la materia
$sql2=("
SELECT 
ni.nivel_descripcion,
es.especiali_descripcion,
cu.curso_descripcion,
pa.paralelo_descripcion,
us.USU_NOMBRE1,
us.USU_NOMBRE2,
us.USU_APELLIDO1,
us.USU_APELLIDO2,
us.ID_USUARIOS,
us.USU_FOTO,
us.ROL

FROM  usuarios us 

INNER JOIN curso cu
ON
us.ID_CURSO=cu.ID_CURSO

INNER JOIN nivel ni
ON
us.ID_NIVEL=ni.ID_NIVEL

INNER JOIN paralelo pa
ON
us.ID_PARALELO=pa.ID_PARALELO

INNER JOIN especialidad es
ON
us.ID_ESPECIALI=es.ID_ESPECIALI

INNER JOIN rol ro
ON
us.rol=ro.ID_ROL

WHERE 
cu.ID_CURSO=$icurso AND
ni.ID_NIVEL=$inivel AND
pa.ID_PARALELO=$iparalelo AND
es.ID_ESPECIALI=$iespecialidad AND
us.ROL=0

ORDER BY  us.USU_APELLIDO1 ASC
");

//AQUI NECESITO HACER UNA CONSULTA A LA TABLA DE NOTAS PARA QUE VALIDE SI YA EXITE UN REGISTRO PERTENECIENTE AL ESTUDIANTE LA MATERIA Y CURSO
//
//
//      ESTA CONSULTA DEBERIA REFLEJAR CON UN ARREGLO ACTUALMENTE LO MUESTRO DE EJEMPLO COMO $arreglo2[10]
//
//      A ESTA CONSULTA EN LA PARTE DE LOS INPUT DENTRO DE LA TABLA TAMBIEN LE QUIERO HACER UN IF empty para que le haga un UPDATE O un INSERT INTO 
//

echo "<table class='table table-hover'  border='1'; >";
echo " <thead>";
echo "<tr class='encabezado_tabla'>";
echo "<th scope='col'>#</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>FOTO</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>NOMBRE</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>NOTA 1</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>NOTA 2</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>NOTA 3</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>NOTA 4</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>PROMEDIO</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";

for ($x = 1; $x <= $row1001[0]; $x++) {//que me haga una secuencia para ordenarlos numericamente los registros concultados
    
$query2=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);
while($arreglo2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){ //blucle para que me muestre todos los registros consultados  
    
echo "
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'>$x </td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><img class=foto_vista_lista src=../FILE_IMAGES/$arreglo2[9]  '/></td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'>$arreglo2[6] $arreglo2[7] $arreglo2[4] $arreglo2[5]</td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><input style='width : 40px; heigth : 13px'; type='text' placeholder='$arreglo2[10]' name='n1'></td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><input style='width : 40px; heigth : 13px'; type='text' placeholder='$arreglo2[10]' name='n2'></td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><input style='width : 40px; heigth : 13px'; type='text' placeholder='$arreglo2[10]' name='n3'></td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><input style='width : 40px; heigth : 13px'; type='text' placeholder='$arreglo2[10]' name='n4'></td>
<td style='vertical-align:middle;'>$arreglo[13]</td>

</tr>
</tbody>

";


}
}
//quiero indicarles que aqui solo estoy mostrando ua lista de estudiantes que estan registrados en ese curso pero quiero luego enviar las notas para que las grabe en la tabla de notas con los input que envía
echo "</table>";

?>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Grabar notas</button>
</form>
</center>
</section>

<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```